# Add new delivery company to Google Now

Tags: google-schemas, google-now

There is a company named Inpost, there are taking care of deliver things to parcel machines. They are sending standard emails with delivery status (received, in transport and on-place) I want to have information about my parcel on Google Now and also I think Google Now should be able to show extra information about parcel based on location (in each email there is a location where you can pick up parcel) I mean, that if I'm in range of parcel machine I should receive information that I can pick it up.

Comment: I get what you're aiming for, but your post is so vague. What have you tried? Do you have any code at all? What platform are you using? Any other information can you provide?

Comment: I'm looking for solution to this case. I was trying to locate developers of Google Now and I've found this page https://developers.google.com/schemas/support so here I am. I can't code, I can only send examples of emails from Inpost.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use *ParcelDelivery* if you want info for the parcel on Google Now.

You can find the documentation here:

https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/parcel-delivery#parcel_delivery_with_shipping_information

The examples shows the parcel as *OrderInTransit* for *OrderStatus*, but if the customer has to pick up the package, you should use *OrderPickupAvailable* instead.